Automatically display the year as "b.C" (before Christ) if the value is negative?
Is there any package that can automatically display the year  as "b.C" (before Christ) if the value is negative?
I've code for that, but I am looking for a more elegant solution, or even better a package that would do this automatically. My solution also seems to generate an extra space afterwards.
I've look through siunitx and datetime2 but none seem to work like I need.
I am using the following (for Portuguese):
\newcommand{\byear}[1]{%
    \ifnum #1<0
    {-#1} a.C.\
    \else
    {#1} d.C.\
    \fi
}


I have a package which lets you configure the labels for BCE and CE. However, it only does that in passing - it isn't something you'd want to load for that purpose.

If you are using that in text the - will make a hyphen not a minus sign, and -4 will print as  --4 as you are not using any arithmetic, just prefixing with a hyphen. perhaps you want \number-#1

you are forcing the extra space with \  use \@% to get a normal (not end of space) behaviour for . wihout adding space.

Don't forget that there was no year zero.  1BC went straight into 1AD.


Using \number to negate the input, and \@ to force a normal . not end of sentence, without adding extra space.
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\byear}[1]{%
    \ifnum #1<0
    {-#1} a.C.\
    \else
    {#1} d.C.\
    \fi
}

\newcommand{\bbyear}[1]{%
    \ifnum #1<0
    \number-#1\ a.C.\@%
    \else
    #1\ d.C.\@%
    \fi
}
\begin{document}

\byear{100}  \byear{-100} \byear{55}

\bbyear{100}  \bbyear{-100} \bbyear{55}



\end{document}


actually the \@ isn't needed as you have a capital here but if the convention used a lowercase letter it would be needed.
